# Change one button class from another button html

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have two button classes that essentially are just 'off' and 'on' images. When a button is pushed, the class of the button switches. Modifying the code im using to turn single buttons on and off, I want to turn one button off when another is turned on, but my getElementByName never seems to work. Is there a better approach?

HTML Buttons:

```
 <input type="button" id="avgbtn" value="2015 Season Avg" class="offgo" onclick="toggleStateavg()" />
<input type="button" id="tradebtn" value="2015 Trade Deadline" class="ongo" onclick="toggleStateavg()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById("avgbtn");
var b = document.getElementById("tradebtn");


function toggleStateavg(){
       if(a.className == "ongo") {
          a.className = "offgo";
          b.className = "ongo";
          avg = "one";
       } else {
          a.className="ongo";
          b.className = "offgo";
          avg = "two";
       }

    }
```

Comment: "... but my getElementByName never seems to work". Because there is no such method. There is `getElementsByName`. Those elements have ID attribute, use the `getElementById` instead.

Comment: It's getElementsByName, not getElementByName.

Comment: Adding the s didnt fix it, I have tried getElementByID as well with no success

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. JavaScript is case-sensitive!

Comment: ^Furthermore, if execution speed is relevant, you probably should `getElementByID` since it's a bit quicker as it only searches for one occurrence of ID whereas you can get a list of names

Comment: I get a "cannot read class name of null" with getElementsById

Comment: NOT plural but `element = document.getElementById(id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <input type="button" id="avgbtn" value="2015 Season Avg" class="offgo" onclick="toggleStateavg()" />
<input type="button" id="tradebtn" value="2015 Trade Deadline" class="ongo" onclick="toggleStateavg()"/>
```

and javascript :

```
function toggleStateavg(){
    var a = document.getElementById("avgbtn");
    var b = document.getElementById("tradebtn");

       if(a.className == "ongo") {
          a.className = "offgo";
          b.className = "ongo";
          avg = "one";
       } else {
          a.className="ongo";
          b.className = "offgo";
          avg = "two";
       }

    }
```

Comment: Oh they were defined in the wrong spot? This works great thank you.

Comment: Probably the javascript block was placed before the html so the element didn't exist "yet" so it was returning null as the inline javascript is executed synchronously with the loading of the page. Since it is placed in the function, it is later reevaluated once the html elements are created and the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
var a = document.getElementByName("avgbtn");
var b = document.getElementByName("tradebtn");
```

to

```
var a = document.getElementById("avgbtn");
var b = document.getElementById("tradebtn");
```

and put these statements inside the

```
function toggleStateavg(){ ... }
```

Comment: This returns a TypeError "cannot read property 'className' of null"

Answer (score 0):

HTML Buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="avgbtn" value="2015 Season Avg" class="offgo" onclick="offgoChangeongo()" />
<input type="button" id="tradebtn" value="2015 Trade Deadline" class="ongo" onclick="ongoChangeoffgo()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function offgoChangeongo() {
    var onGo = document.getElementById("tradebtn");
    var offGo = document.getElementById("avgbtn");
    onGo.className = offGo.className;
}
function ongoChangeoffgo() {
    var offgo = document.getElementById("avgbtn");
    var ongo = document.getElementById("tradebtn");
    offgo.className = ongo.className;
```